# Telerik Native Transition href load slow

Tags: javascript, telerik, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, telerik-appbuilder

i just use Telerik Transition plugin into my phonegap project.I have 2 html page.when click to second page,the slide transition working,but the problem is, the slide transition will redirect to same page and after few second change to second page.How can i implement so that when i click button in first page it will fast redirect to second page html.i want redirect to signup.html fast when click button from first page.Thank you

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function()   {   
 $("#signup").click(function(){
 window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.slide({
 "href":"signup.html",
 "direction":"left", //left is defaults
 "slowdownfactor" : 3
 });        
 });   
 });

<a id="signup" href="javascript:void(0)"   style="text-decoration: none">
<h6 align="center"  style="margin-top:30px">Register Now</h6>
</a>
```

Comment: Try removing `href="javascript:void(0)"`, that may be screwing something up.

Comment: If i remove that or i just put href="#" the page transition will not happen :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [sample app](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions-DemoApp/tree/master/Native%20Page%20Transitions) provided with the plugin. In the code you can see an example of proper usage:

```
    <a onclick="slideBaby()">eigth page (livesynced, slide)!</a>
    <script>
      function slideBaby() {
        var options = {
          "direction" : "right",
          "href" : "eigth.html"
        };
        window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.flip(
          options,
          function (msg) {alert("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(msg))},
          function (msg) {alert("ERROR: "   + JSON.stringify(msg))}
        );
      }
    </script>
```